# Disable drop zone if there is already item - ngx-smooth-dnd

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, drag

I use [ngx-smooth-dnd](https://kutlugsahin.github.io/ngx-smooth-dnd/) and I need to disable drop place after there is already dropped one item.

I try to use `onDragStart`, `onDragEnd`, `onDropReady`

Component.html

```
 <smooth-dnd-container
  [groupName]="'dropZoneGroup'"
  (drop)="onDrop($event)"
  (dragStart)="onDragStart($event)"
>
  <smooth-dnd-draggable>
    <div
      [input]="data"
    ></div>
  </smooth-dnd-draggable>
</smooth-dnd-container>
```

Component.ts

```
  @Input() input;

  constructor() { }

  onDrop(dropResult) {

    if (this.data.length > 0) {
       return;
    }

      this.data= applyDrag(this.data, dropResult);

  }

// Also try call onDragStart, but nothing change

  onDragStart({ isSource, payload, willAcceptDrop }) {
    return ({ isSource: false, payload, willAcceptDrop: true })
  }

// Also try this but doesn't working

onDropReady(dropResult: IDropResult) {
   const { removedIndex, addedIndex, payload, element } = dropResult;
        if(addedIndex > 0){
           return;
        }
        this.data= applyDrag(this.data, dropResult);
}
```

You can see all of this and try here [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-smooth-dnd-testing-with-dynamic-ptwaeh?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Well. I cannot comment, so adding it as an answer.
try shouldAcceptDrop event on container, like:

```
<smooth-dnd-container
          [groupName]="'1'"
          [getChildPayload]="getChildPayload2"
          (drop)="onDrop($event)"
          (dragStart)="onDragStart($event)"
          [shouldAcceptDrop]="hasNoChild"
        >
          <smooth-dnd-draggable *ngFor="let item of items2">
            <div class="draggable-item">
              {{ item.data }}
            </div>
          </smooth-dnd-draggable>
        </smooth-dnd-container>
```

and in your class:

```
constructor() {

    ...

    this.hasNoChild = this.hasNoChild.bind(this);

    ...

  }

  ...

  hasNoChild() {
    return !this.items2 || this.items2.length === 0;
  }
```